# Detecting swipe movements to go to another web page on an ipad web app

Tags: iphone, ipad, web-applications, swipe

I'm currently trying to set up an iPad web app. I have my home page but want the user to swipe left  and be taken to the about page. I have found a way of detecting movement from padilicious.com but don't know how to make the swipe change the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given you use the movement detection from [padilicious](http://padilicious.com/code/touchevents/index.html):

```
if ( swipeDirection == 'left' ) {
    window.location.href = 'about.html';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. If I wanted the movement to the other page to be a slide would I have to store the contents of each page in another div and then have the finger swipe move the page to the selected div?

Comment: Yes, or you could have the contents of the page next page be loaded dynamically via ajax into the div (probably not as smooth, though)